# Why does Resharper say "Arguments Mismatch" if I don't explicitly supply optional parameter?

Tags: resharper, optional-parameters, default-arguments

My project uses .Net 4.0 Client.

The following code snippet

```
#if DEBUG
    string key = "pldi6z3n3vfz23czhano";
#else
    string key = "bh7aaqmlmd0bhd48g3ye";
#endif
    using (new Analytics(key, userInfo))...
```

compiles and runs fine in both Debug and Release configurations. However if the Debug configuration is active in Visual Studio, Resharper red-underlines the parameters I'm passing to the Analytics constructor and says "Arguments Mismatch". It offers no options to fix the problem, and since it thinks it's an error, as opposed to a warning, it doesn't offer to suppress it. If I add a third argument, true, then it's completely happy. The third argument to the constructor has a default value of true, so it shouldn't be necessary to pass it explicitly. Of course, it's no problem for me to do so, but I'm baffled by Resharper's behavior.

If it matters, the Analytics class is from DesktopAnalytics version 1.0.1 created by John Hatton (downloaded using NuGet).

Resharper version is 7.1.3 Full Edition.

Comment: When ReSharper is giving the red squiggly "Argument mismatch", what does the parameter info for the method say? Does it think the `Analytics` constructor have different parameters?

Comment: I have 7.1.3 and do not see the issue you do. As you mention below, it sounds like a caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

This works correctly for me using Resharper 8.0 - I do have a recollection of R# not handling pre-processor directives nicely in earlier versions - thus it is likely fixed already. It might be fixed in your version by moving your `key` declaration outside your pre-processor directives (that is a wild guess)

[image]

Comment: Tried that. No dice. Upgraded to Resharper 8.2.1, and problem persists. I'm thinking it might somehow be a problem where Resharper has cached info from a previous version of the DesktopAnalytics DLL, but clearing the Resharper cache doesn't fix it.

Comment: @TomBogle how did u clear the R# cache? you might also want to delete the folders completely - eg `C:\Users\wal\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v7.1`

Comment: I had just used the Clear Caches button on the Resharper options page in VS. Just tried your idea, but it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I tried clearing caches both from the UI and deleting folders. Rebooted reloaded solution (many times) other similar projects were fine.

I don't have the terminology but there are two properties settings areas.  One shows up as a big dialog.  With Application, Build, Build Events, Debug etc. tabs. The other one shows up when I simply left-click the project file in solution explorer.  It has 6 Name-Value options.  The first one was "C# Language Level" and it was somehow set to C# 3.0 (which did not support optional arguments).  Setting it to C# 4.0 fixed all the issues.  Note I was building x86 for .Net Framework 4.0.  I was running a matching NUnit.

At any rate this change fixed the problem for me.  I don't know how this happened.